# Check if table exists using command

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to write a method to check if a table exists. I am trying to use the using statement to keep it consistent through my database.

```
public void checkTableExists()
{
    connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\keith_000\Documents\ZuriRubberDressDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    string tblnm = "BasicHours";
    string str = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = " + tblnm + ");";

    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    int count = 0;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(str, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The count is " + count);

                    myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                    myReader.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("Table Exists!");
                    MessageBox.Show("The count is " + count);
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sql issue");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Major issue");
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Table exists");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Table doesn't exists");
    }
}
```

It throws an exception when it hits the try block. It catches in the `SqlException` block.

This is the point where I am learning to interact with databases again. The solution would be good, but more importantly, a brief explanation of where I have need to learn how to improve my code.

Thanks

Keith

Comment: TABLE_NAME is a string field. You need single quotes around your variable, but better use a parameter

Comment: Please don't concatenate SQL queries like that. (tblnm = "BasicHours; TRUNCATE TABLE [BasicHours];" Use Parameterised SqlCommand objects instead.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code fails because when you write directly a query searching for a string value then this value should be enclosed in single quotes like 'BasicHours'.

However there are some improvements to apply to your actual code.
First, you can use a simplified sql command.
Second, you use parameters instead of string concatenations.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"IF EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table) 
  SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@table", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tblName;
int exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(exists == 1)
    // Table exists
```

This command text don't require you to use an SqlDataReader because the query returns just one row with one 'column' and the value of this single cell is either 1 or 0.
A lot less overhead.

A part from this, it is of uttermost importance, that you never build sql queries concatenating strings. This method is well know to cause problems. 
The worse is called [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and could potentially destroy your database or reveal confidential information to hackers. The minor ones are crashes when the string concatenated contains single quotes. Use always a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following code in my project and worked for me:

```
 try
 {
     using (con = new SqlConnection(Constr);)
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = $"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = '{tableName}') SELECT 1 ELSE Select 0;"
             Exists = int.Parse(sqlQuery.ExecuteScalar().ToString())==1;
             con.Close();
         }

  }
  catch{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the line: `string tblnm = "BasicHours";`. You table name is a string and should be apostrophed, try this: `string tblnm = "'BasicHours'";`

Inside catch blocks you could also log exception messages and details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on this issue. This is the solution that I'm implemnenting.

```
    public void checkTableExists()
    {
        connectionString = @" 
        Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
        AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\keith_000\Documents\ZuriRubberDressDB.mdf;
        Integrated Security=True;
        Connect Timeout=30";

        string tblName = @"BasicHours";
        string str = @"IF EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table) 
                SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(str, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, connection);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@table", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tblName;
                    int exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (exists == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Table exists");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Table doesn't exists");
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sql issue");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Major issue");
        }
    }
```